# pifont (zapf dingbats) shows wrong letters

Tags: fonts

The following code should print out arrows, but shows completely different letters instead:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\[
  \ding{52} \quad \ding{222} \quad \ding{237} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Print them in normal text mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\begin{document}
\[ \textrm{\ding{52} \quad \ding{222} \quad \ding{237}} \]
\end{document}
```